# Named Route not found when accessing action directly, but found when accessing via AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a named route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "OfficeByZipCode",
    url: "RetrieveOffice/ZipCode/{zipcode}",
    defaults: new { controller = "RLO", action = "RetrieveOfficeByZipCode" }
    );
```

I am retrieving the named route within an action:

```
public ActionResult RetrieveByZipCode(string zipCode)
{
    try
    {
        Office obj = null;
        string urlOffice;
        //build a route dictionary that includes the zip code
        RouteValueDictionary route = new RouteValueDictionary
        {
            {"zipcode", zipCode}
        };
        //build the relative path for the route to retrieve JSON data
        VirtualPathData vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "OfficeByZipCode", route);
        //combine the relative path with the site's root path
        //use the config value rather than HttpContext.Current.Request.Url to overcome issues that arise from Load Balancers and SSL offloading 
        urlOffice = String.Concat(Properties.Settings.Default.RootUrl, vpd.VirtualPath);
        //the rest of the code. not important for this example
```

Now, I am accessing this action in one of two ways:

One, via AJAX, from a different page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Test/RetrieveByZipCode",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(formData),
    dataType: "html",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (data) {
        $("#content").html(data);
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Two, directly via the browser:

```
http://localhost/RLOService/test/RetrieveByZipCode/92677
```

When accessing the action directly, this line comes back null:

```
VirtualPathData vpd = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "OfficeByZipCode", route);
```

But, it works just fine when calling the same action via AJAX.

The obvious difference between the two is one I am accessing via POST (AJAX) and the other I am accessing via GET (URL). If I change the AJAX action to GET, I receive the same error. Why would this make a difference?

Comment: it is expecting a URL as http://host..../RetrieveOffice/ZipCode/{zipcode} and your direct URl doesnt match with it

Comment: @HaBo: I'm not sure what you mean. How does that explain the difference in behavior between POST and GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your GET Url to make zipCode a parameter (e.g., `http://localhost/RLOService/test/RetrieveByZipCode?zipCode=92677`)